# How do I enable TLS on an Apache Arrow FlightClient in Java?

Tags: java, tls1.2, apache-arrow, apache-arrow-flight

The [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/java/reference/org/apache/arrow/flight/FlightClient.Builder.html) for the Java Apache Arrow (`v11.0.0`) `FlightClient.Builder` has several methods related to constructing a TLS-enabled client:

- `clientCertificate(InputStream clientCertificate, InputStream clientKey)`
- `useTls()`
- `overrideHostname(String hostname)`
- `trustedCertificates(InputStream stream)`
- `verifyServer(boolean verifyServer)`

The descriptions aren't detailed enough for me to understand which ones are needed to enable and use TLS in connections with a `FlightServer`. There could easily be some gap in my understanding of TLS that would help me more easily consume this documentation.

Do I need to use all of these? Are some of them redundant? How are they related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look [at the code that implements this API](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/java/flight/flight-core/src/main/java/org/apache/arrow/flight/FlightClient.java) for some insights.

`useTls` simply tells the underlying client builder to start putting together SSL Context for the TLS-enabled client. The same effect is achieved by having the `grpc+tls` scheme attached to the location attribute.

The rest of the options are used for adding to the SSL Context. The context builder is provided by `io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder`.

- `clientCertificate(cert, key)` adds the provided cert/key to the SSL Context's key manager.
- `trustedCertificates(cert)` adds the provided cert to the trust manager (for third party connection verification).
- `verifyServer(bool)` cannot be `false` if either of the above two are provided, since they are required to verify the server. If this is `false`, the trust manager will simply be set up using `InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE`.
- `overrideHostname(hostname)` calls the underlying `overrideAuthority()` on the channel builder. This isn't really related to what I'm trying to do.

Do I need to use all of these (ignoring `overrideHostname`)? It depends on how the TLS is configured on the server the client will connect to.

Are any of them redundant? `useTls()` is redundant if the `location` attribute already has the TLS scheme attached.